# SharePoint 2016 On Premise Using Azure AD

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am trying to connect SharePoint 2016 On Premise configured with Azure AD authentication.
Users have access to the site through Azure AD federation authentication.  Basically, its browser based after successful login it redirects users to SP site with FedAuth cookie and it working fine.
I am trying to connect site from C#/ASP.NET MVC applications, tried different frameworks/solutions nothing did not work. Please help ne anyone have solution for the application connection to SharePoint 2016 On Premise Using Azure AD.

Thank you!

Tried to get Bearer token using oauth, was able to get valid token using postman. but connecting back to SP site with help of token did not work getting 401 invalid JWT token error.